# openapi-request-validator Validate against yaml

Tags: node.js, npm, openapi

Please let me know if openapi-request-validator nodejs library can be used to validate request against open api 3 spec yaml file. I had a look at express-openapi-validator, but my application does not use expressjs. My service is a lambda function (nodejs) deployed in aws.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in your lambda function you can use `openapi-request-validator`, which already makes it's function signature very friendly to the openapi spec yaml file. What you can do:

1. Include the openapi spec yaml file in the zip file when deploying to AWS.
2. At runtime, load the yaml file and convert it into a Javascript object using some library (e.g. `js-yaml`).
3. write a simple function to do the following:

- Look up the Javascript spec object based on the request path to find out related parameters, requestBody, schemas etc required by `OpenAPIRequestValidator`.
- Transform the incoming API Gateway proxy event object (I assume it's proxy integration) into the format that `validateRequest` expects.
- Then you will be able to new `OpenAPIRequestValidator` and call its `validateRequest` method to validate the transformed request object.